# Кешируется ли require?

Tags: node.js

У меня получается, что require кеширует переменную и она одна и та же для каждого запроса. А как сделать так, чтобы require создавал каждый раз новый объект?

```
let Handlebars = require('handlebars');
console.log(Handlebars.count); // 50
Handlebars.count = 0;
Handlebars.count = 50;
```

Comment: `require` загружает модуль. Модуль - это часть вашей программы. Как часть работающей программы может измениться?

Comment: Кеширует и это написано в документации.

Comment: Лучше напишите задачу которую вы пытаетесь решить, а мы попробуем найти правильное решение.

Comment: Решение нашел. У handlebars есть метод create. Он создаёт не глобальный экземпляр. А по умолчанию он глобальный. 

 var GlobalHandlebars = require('handlebars');
    var Handlebars = GlobalHandlebars.create();

Comment: Если наши решение, то добавьте его как ответ. (Вы наверное привыкли к PHP, в котором в каждом запросе всё заново начинается. В случае Node.js ваша программа запускается один раз и работает всё время пока обрабатывает запросы. Например, благодаря этому вы теоретически можете из одного запроса посмотреть что делает другой запрос.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Require кешируется, посмотреть можно в require.cache. Но трогать этот кеш не рекомендуется.
В данном случае, более правильно создавать новый экземпляр handlebars, а не использовать глобальный объект.

```
let GlobalHandlebars = require('handlebars'); 
let Handlebars = GlobalHandlebars.create();
```